# Does Objective C implementation is much slower plain C? (optimization)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, ios, algorithm

I'm working on painting application and implementing flood fill.
I implemented it using Objective C but without using any Apple's framework. Basically algorithm was ported from plain C.

At the moment there are 2 implementations - Floodfill4 anf Scanline floodfill.
Both spend around 5secs on iPad to fill 800x600 rectangle.
Here is my algorithm:
https://github.com/OgreSwamp/ObjFloodFill/blob/master/src/FloodFill.m

Do you think it is worth to invest some time to port it to pure C. Will I have sighnificant performance increase?
Do you see any other way to increase performance?

Thanks!

Comment: Objective-C is a strict superset of C.  Which means that your floodfill should already be a C program.  If you are using Objective-C facilities in your time-critical code, then you have a problem with your algorithm and your choice of tools, not the tool itself.  In other words, if you have a routine that is time-critical, you should have coded it in "pure C" even in an Objective-C program.

Comment: may you want to ask here: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: C implementation didn't help much. It still around 5 seconds for 800x600

Comment: Five seconds to draw a black box?  Yikes, you deffinately need some optimization.

Answer (score 1):

The main performance issue of Objective C is method call - it is slower than standard C call.
However, if you don't use subroutine calls a lot it would not affect performance.
However, 5 seconds for 800x600 is very slow for modern processors, so you actually should optimize your code.

Comment: Just took a look at your code - you actually call subroutines too often, for each pixel, which is very slow.

Comment: But how would you offer to compare colors than, without calling functions. 
PS: Implementation on C didn't save any significant time...

Comment: do you think it will be faster to convert RGBA buffer to array[][] of color struct and then compare color.r, color.g, color.b for equality?

Comment: It would be faster to store each color as uint32, and compare the whole color at once

Comment: Nikolay, that's not so easy. 1. I need to chqck them for equality (easy in your case). If original color alpha is less than some value we need to mix color. And we need also to check if color similar as edges of brush are not exact red in case of red color.